# IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python

Olá, estou executando um simples código python (2.7.3) para lançar uma mensagem por webhook no Discord e estou encontrando o seguinte erro:

```
  urlopen(url).read()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 207, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 436, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1161, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 381, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()

IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

O código que está sendo executado é esse:

```
from urllib import urlopen
url = 'https://minhaurl.com/webhook.php'
urlopen(url).read()
```

Obs: Não há erro no arquivo PHP porque usei ele antes.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando usar `https` e não `http`, e para isso, são necessárias várias libs de criptografia instaladas e em versão atualizada. O python 2.7.3 é *ancião* (foi lançado a mais de 6 anos atrás) e muita coisa mudou nesse campo desde que ele foi lançado.

A tecnologia de cifragem (ssl) foi atualizada várias vezes nesse período. Tente atualizar o seu python para a versão mais nova. Se você tiver o pyOpenSSL, atualize ele também.

Comment: Obrigado, eu não tinha percebido isso antes.